# 95mm circular polarizer: B+W, Sigma, or other?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, filters, sigma

I'm looking for a high quality circular polarizing filter to fit a Sigma 150-600 zoom lens with a 95mm diameter, and the options at this size seem somewhat limited. Notably, the Hoya Pro1 CPL that's won a lot of praise here doesn't seem to be available in the 95mm size. After doing some research, it looks like the two best choices are:

- [B+W 95mm HTC Kaesemann Circular Polarizer with Multi-Resistant Coating](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00R698AF0)
- [Sigma 95mm WR CPL Filter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NIHCUN2)

Has anyone compared these two filters? I'm having trouble finding much information about the Sigma in particular -- I'd like to know whether it's a high transmissivity design like the B+W, and also whether it's weather sealed at the edges like the B+W apparently is.

I'd also welcome pointers to any other good options I should consider. 95mm seems to be relatively uncommon size.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. B&H has quite a few of these, made by B+W, Heliopan, Singh-Ray, and others, notably, Hoya and Hitech. Those brands are all very good (especially their higher end filters, but really, they all are very good), and all have 95mm CPL filter models around the $200-400 US price point. The B+W you mentioned will work fine; personally, if I was going to spend $200 or more on a filter, those brands would be my choices. I haven't seen Sigma filters; they would also probably work fine, but if I could get an equivalent filter from one of the brands I mentioned, I wouldn't give the Sigma a second thought.

They will all polarize light, and the brands I mentioned have a minimum of color casts or other undesirable effects.

I think a polarizer on a lens that long would have limited utility for me, but far be it from me to question someone's creativity!

Answer (score 0):

Beware that this lens (I own it) doesn't like filters, even high-quality ones. You will probably lose about 20% resolution.  I tested a Hasselblad 95mm UV to find this out.  The same filter on shorter-focal length lenses was fine. You might want to read this article: https://www.photoartfromscience.com/single-post/2017/05/11/Do-Long-Lenses-Not-Like-Filters

Comment: That's interesting, but you seem to have only tested one copy of the lens against one copy of a filter, so why do you think you can generalize that one experience to a blanket statement like *this lens doesn't like filters*?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is *this filter doesn't like long lenses*?